# Setting cookie domain not working for ASP.NET MVC OWIN SSO

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, cross-domain, owin

I was doing asp.net mvc owin sso for two web site.

I do some research for this, here is some point need to know.

- Machine KEY must be the same
- Cookie must be the same

But it come to a problem to me.

1. When I set the cookie domain, the mvc application doesn't get auth info, always redirect to login page.
2. When I comment the cookie domain, everything is fine.

So I am wondering, the cookie domain must be real domain, not the fake?

two web site are published in my local IIS

- http://localhost:1000  for a website
- http://localhost:2000  for b website

Here is cookie config info:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // need to add UserManager into owin, because this is used in cookie invalidation
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = MyAuthentication.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
            CookieDomain = "mycompany.com",
            CookieName = "companysso",
            CookieHttpOnly = true
        });
    }
```

Both website have same cookie config and machine key, but not working for me.

Would someone know what's happening here?

I can't figure it out by myself, so please help me.